# flutter: 'package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart': Failed assertion: line 487 pos 12: 'email != null': is not true

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase and keep getting this annoying message when I click on the Login button :

> flutter: 'package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart': Failed assertion: line 487 pos 12: 'email != null': is not true.

The code works fine. The app is built and run successfully. This happens when I enter my email and password and click on the login button. Referred to these threads: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22028 , [_AssertionError ('package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart': Failed assertion: line 95 pos 12: 'email != null': is not true.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431797/assertionerror-packagefirebase-auth-src-firebase-auth-dart-failed-assertio) but none helped. Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

My code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Auth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthState createState() => _AuthState();
}

class _AuthState extends State<Auth> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _password = TextEditingController(),
      _email = TextEditingController(),
      _phone = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String email;
  String password;

  bool willLogin = true;
  bool showPassword = false;
  void _login() async {
    _formKey.currentState.validate();
    try {
      final existingUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      if (existingUser != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _signup() async {
    _formKey.currentState.validate();
    try {
      final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      if (newUser != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Dog SOS"),
        leading: Icon(Icons.pets),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Center(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.shield,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 50,
                ),
                radius: 60,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            if (!willLogin) ...[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Phone",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                controller: _phone,
                validator: (value) =>
                    value.isEmpty ? "Please Enter Phone Number" : null,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
            ],
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              controller: _email,
              validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? "Please Enter Email" : null,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    showPassword
                        ? Icons.visibility_off_outlined
                        : Icons.visibility_outlined,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      showPassword = !showPassword;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              obscureText: !showPassword,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              controller: _password,
              validator: (value) =>
                  value.isEmpty ? "Please Enter Password" : null,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              child: Text(
                willLogin ? "\nLOGIN\n" : "\nSIGN UP\n",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .button
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState.save();
                  _login();
                }
              },
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(willLogin
                    ? "Don't have an account?"
                    : "Already have an account?"),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    willLogin ? "Create One." : "Login.",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.copyWith(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      willLogin = !willLogin;
                      _signup();
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like email == null at the time you're trying to use it.

Comment: @DougStevenson, how do i fix that? Can you help me what changes in code I'll have to make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  String email;
  String password;
```

Both of those are null, they are not referencing anything. You have to do the following, first bind the controller to the field which you are already doing then:

```
 void _login() async {
    _formKey.currentState.validate();
    try {
      final existingUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _email.text, password: _password.text);
      if (existingUser != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Use the property `text` of the class `TextEditingController` to get the value of `_email` and `_password`.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Yeah I was trying to, but stack overflow doesn't like speed it seems, it asks me to wait for 2 more minutes to mark it as correct haha:) Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Peter Haddad I am sorry to bother you again, the solution you mentioned worked well with the login. I have another button (Create one) which will be used to create a new account. When clicking on that button I get this Exception during the runtime : `PlatformException (PlatformException(weak-password, Password should be at least 6 characters, {code: weak-password, message: Password should be at least 6 characters, nativeErrorMessage: The password must be 6 characters long or more., nativeErrorCode: 17026, additionalData: {}}, null))`

Comment: the password should be more than 6 characters

Comment: I get it. But when I press on the 'Create one' button it shows this. It doesn't take me to my signup function

Comment: yes because this an error from firebase. You get this error from this method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` This is  a restriction added from firebase auth

Comment: Hi @Peter Haddad , that got solved thanks. Now I get similar error when trying to click on the Sign UP button. flutter: `'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_user_credential.dart': Failed assertion: line 14 pos 16: 'data != null': is not true.`

Comment: Any problem in the signup function or somewhere in the end?

Comment: please ask it as a different question, and specify where you get this error

Comment: done! Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65337850/flutter-assertion-error-flutter-packagefirebase-auth-platform-interface-src