# Flutter Assertion Error: flutter: 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_user_credential.dart': Failed assertion

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase and keep getting this annoying message when I click on the Sign Up button :

> flutter:
> 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_user_credential.dart':
> Failed assertion: line 14 pos 16: 'data != null': is not true.

The code works fine. The app is built and run successfully. This happens when I enter my phone, email and password and click on the signup button. My code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Auth extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthState createState() => _AuthState();
}

class _AuthState extends State<Auth> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _password = TextEditingController(),
      _email = TextEditingController(),
      _phone = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  bool willLogin = true;
  bool showPassword = false;
  void _login() async {
    _formKey.currentState.validate();
    try {
      final existingUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _email.text, password: _password.text);
      if (existingUser != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _signup() async {
    _formKey.currentState.validate();
    try {
      final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _email.text, password: _password.text);
      if (newUser != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Dog SOS"),
        leading: Icon(Icons.pets),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Center(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.shield,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 50,
                ),
                radius: 60,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            if (!willLogin) ...[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Phone",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                controller: _phone,
                validator: (value) =>
                    value.isEmpty ? "Please Enter Phone Number" : null,
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
            ],
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Email",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              controller: _email,
              validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? "Please Enter Email" : null,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    showPassword
                        ? Icons.visibility_off_outlined
                        : Icons.visibility_outlined,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      showPassword = !showPassword;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              obscureText: !showPassword,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              controller: _password,
              validator: (value) =>
                  value.isEmpty ? "Please Enter Password" : null,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              ),
              child: Text(
                willLogin ? "\nLOGIN\n" : "\nSIGN UP\n",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .button
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState.save();
                  _login();
                }
              },
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(willLogin
                    ? "Don't have an account?"
                    : "Already have an account?"),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text(
                    willLogin ? "Create One." : "Login.",
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.copyWith(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      willLogin = !willLogin;
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        _formKey.currentState.save();
                        _signup();
                      }
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: are you able to signup?

Comment: Nope. As soon as I click on the sign up button, it gives me this message even though I have filled all the necessary fields (phone, email and password)

Comment: inside the try block do print(_email.text) and print(_password.text),  then inside `if (existingUser != null) {` write `print("exists");` and tell me what you get

Comment: Shouldn't it be change in the signup function meaning I will change if (newUser != null) instead of what you mentioned?

Comment: no, just add the print statement to see what you get or debug it

Comment: It doesn't print anything. The same message again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226082/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-haardik-dharma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that here:

```
  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      willLogin = !willLogin;
                      if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                        _formKey.currentState.save();
                        _signup();
                      }
                    });
                  },
```

on click of this button, you are using `setState` and assign `willLogin` equal to false, therefore it is not even calling `_signup()` since it is immediately calling the `build()` method. So now you have `willLogin = false`, which is showing you this in the screen this widget:

```
child: Text(
                willLogin ? "\nLOGIN\n" : "\nSIGN UP\n",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .button
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState.save();
                  _login();
                }
              },
            ),
```

Here according to your code if willLogin is false then show `Sign up` text and call `_login()` method. Since you are calling `_login()` method for sign up you are getting this error since the user is not even registered in firebase authentication.

---

What you need to do is change the logic, either remove `setState`, this way `_signup()` method will be called, or keep it as it is but change `_login()` to `_signup()`.

Try the following:

```
child: Text(
                willLogin ? "\nLOGIN\n" : "\nSIGN UP\n",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .button
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  _formKey.currentState.save();
                  willLogin ? _login() : _signup();
                }
              },
            ),
```